# Regex matching a two-segment word starting with X, and only match the first segment if the second segment ends with Y

Tags: regex

I'm writing a regular expression that will match a two-segment word starting with X. If the second segment doesn't end with Y it'll match both segments, but match the first segment if the second segment ends with Y.

For example,

```
XJohn.Doe -> matches XJohn.Doe
XJane.DoeY -> matches XJane (or XJane.)
ZJanie.Doe -> not match
```

What I've got so far is

```
X[A-z]+?\.[A-z]+(?<!Y)$
```

which doesn't match *XJane.DoeY* at all, or

```
X[A-z]+?\.[A-z]+(?<!Y)
```

which matches *XJane.Doe*.

How can I modify the regex so that if the match fails, it'll try to only match the first segment.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below,

```
^X[A-Za-z]+\.(?:[A-Za-z]+(?<!Y)$|)
```

Change `+` in `X[A-Za-z]+` to `*` if you want to match also the strings like `X.X`.

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/oI2jF9/6)

**Update:**

```
^X[A-Za-z]+\.(?:[A-Za-z]+(?<![\WY])$|)
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/oI2jF9/8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex based on word boundaries:

```
\bX\w*\W+(?:\w*[^Y\W])?\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM9nO9/1)

---

**EDIT:** Based on comment below following regex can work:

```
\bX\w*(?:\W+\S*[^!\s](?=\s|$))?
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/wM9nO9/4)

Comment: Thanks! But I forgot that the ending character (Y in my previous example some time might be a non-word character, such as !). How can I modify your RE to work for this case as well?